# Sqldf: convert and select

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, sqldf

I'm trying to read a SQL database in R (sqldf, postgresql) but on one column there has to be some restrictions (convert and select). The column I want to adjust contains three possible elements (all as strings), namely the empty string, four numbers or four numbers followed by a space and two characters. An example could be

```
"2378", "", "4329", "4193 AM", "2195"
```

I only want to keep the elements that are real numbers and between 1000 and 1200 (and converted to int instead of string types). The name of the column is "post" and this is what I've got so far

```
query = "
SELECT *, cast(post as int) as postConv
FROM base
WHERE length(post) > 0 and
length(post) < 5
"
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the selection happen such that the new converted numbers have only values between 1000 and 1200. For now, an extra column 'postConv' will be made, but is it also possible that the converted elements are just stored in the column 'post'?

Comment: Should a value of "1100 AM" be returned, but as 1100? It is between 1000 and 1200 but has the text "AM" beside it. Just want to clarify what you want to do w/ those.

Comment: No, I don't want to keep those values.

Comment: `where post between 1000 and 1200`

Comment: This doesn't work because the elements are strings

Comment: -1 Have you tried it?  I guess not, since it does work.

Comment: I actually did. Added the line "and between 1000 and 1200" after the code above, but resulting in an error (Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= integer)). Based on the answer below I still had to add apostrophes around 1000 and 1200. No need to downvote in my opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
select *
  from base
 where col between '1000' and '1200'
   and col not like '% %'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1402b/3/0

But this assumes the strings you want not considered real numbers always contain a space, whereas those you don't want filtered out do not contain a space. In your example data this will work.

In the fiddle, "1100 AM" is not returned because it contains a blank space within the string. 1100 is not filtered out, because it is between 1000 and 1200, and does not contain a blank space.